# How to build video conference web app based on SRS ( Simple Realtime Server - https://github.com/ossrs/srs ) - WebRTC

Tags: node.js, webrtc, jitsi, video-conferencing, simple-realtime-server

I've already built Live Video Streaming web app using SRS ( Simple Realtime Server [https://github.com/ossrs/srs](https://stackoverflow.com)  ) - RTMP protocol and FFMpeg Socket Server Module( [https://github.com/chenxiaoqino/getusermedia-to-rtmp](https://stackoverflow.com) ).

And now I need to add video conference ( video group chat ) to my own web app using SRS.

I know SRS provide WebRTC, couldn't find any document or example to configure video conference in SRS documents.

It says only 'On the way' for video conference section of the SRS docs ( [https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/blog/video-chat-live](https://stackoverflow.com) ).

Is there any reusable examples to build video chat app using SRS-WebRTC?
Maybe the module will have room management, call-management, share screens, video/screen recording, signaling, text chat, mute and so on like Jitsi Meet.

If SRS doesn't provide the additional modules for video chat, shall I use Jitsi Meet or this [repository](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/video-conferencing) ?

can I build free video conference app that can support unlimited users using JitsiMeet module and my own servers?

Heard JitsiMeet charges much money for over 25 monthly active users.

Comment: See this https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/webrtc#sfu-video-room